# ExpressJS requests hang on Mongoose save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

On my server when I run

```
Apples.insertAll( [objects], function(err,docs){ .. logic ..})
```

the requests I send to the express router starts hanging, I get about 20-30 seconds before it returns a simple response without calculations

The flow is as below:

My server get a POST request with some information, checks if the request was received already and then sends a response back to the client, (if its an old request it just returns a response)

If the request was sent for the first time the server will start to process it
What happens next is I have an observer with subsribers and I send an event to all of them (this method is without a callback), if it belongs to that service it starts working on it, the service downloads some data from another server and store it in my database for later use (about 30k objects)

Before I save the data I normalize it and then save it, I save (in a batch command) `Apples.insertAll( [array], (err,docs) => { .. logic ..})`
(There 12 function of these for each type of object)

I run all the 12 functions with `async.series` Then I return all the object back to the service so I could pass them on to the next application

On this current step, when I send a request to the express the responses hangs until the whole save for all object will be completed

I "solved" my problem forking this service with child_process but **I dont feel that this is a right way** to solve this issue, it will complicate debuggin the future and beside that NodeJS ment to be single threaded

On the profiler I can see that on these operations the callTicks are very long so something must be blocking the express operations

I hope I made some sence in my question, Thanks for any help offered :)

Comment: Drill down your question to problem itself, people don't like to parse bunch of words and show some coDes